# Automated prompt for system details

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

Could there be a system that, for certain tags, like [freeze](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/freeze), or [crash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/crash), gives a friendly prompt to the user to give details like the output of `lspci` or the Xorg logs before the question is posted, but allows you to bypass these with a confirmation, saving time for users that didn't know to post their logs or other info?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## No

We're not a bug tracker. If you're posting topics about [freeze](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/freeze) or [crash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/crash) (and if you read back in meta you'll know *why* you shouldn't) you need to be using Apport and Launchpad.

This has been asked several times, the platform Stack Exchange really doesn't support prompting people for details. However, people can add the details to tag wikis so those who do look at the tag wikis can see what useful commands can be run to improve their post.

Comment: What about details for hardware enablement? Based on closures I've seen it seems the community thinks questions about configuring around HW-specific graphics/audio/device problems are okay-ish.

Comment: This has been asked several times, the platform Stack Exchange really doesn't support prompting people for details. However, people can add the details to tag wikis so those who do look at the tag wikis can see what useful commands can be run to improve their post.