# We need to improve the [system]

Tags: discussion, tags

What's a system? Objectively speaking without context, anything can be a [system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/system). From biology, ecology, astronomy, computer science, specific programs, etc. There's no bounds to what you can call a system. This tag needs to go. The only problem is finding a good replacement for it, ie:

- [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes) which tag could we create?
- [How can I find the version of Ubuntu that is installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12493/how-can-i-find-the-version-of-ubuntu-that-is-installed) seems like release-management question?
- [Whats the difference between Unix, Linux and Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183723/whats-the-difference-between-unix-linux-and-ubuntu) huh?
- [Is there a way to move/remove "system settings" from the shut-down menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44171/is-there-a-way-to-move-remove-system-settings-from-the-shut-down-menu) easy peasy. [system-settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/system-settings)
- [How do I create an encrypted filesystem inside a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58935/how-do-i-create-an-encrypted-file-system-inside-a-file) [filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/filesystem) + [encryption](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/encryption)?

I got bored, but those are that at single glance I can't think about a tag. The rest I have an idea but will take time to fix :(. BTW, just removing the tag is no good, several of those questions are mistagged and needs another tag or create a tag.

Comment: `Freeze` for first one.

`System-info` for 2nd.

If there was an operating system tag, that might work. (Like I said to you in chat it is still broad though)

`filesystem-encryption` would be a good tag because encryption can be network, file, or just the keys.

Comment: @NoTime [freeze is a bad tag.](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3413/automated-prompt-for-system-details/3414#3414)

Comment: OK I see. Is there actually a purpose for the tag, as it says most posts will be considered off topic, and most likely closed? As in a filter for bad questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/system) can apply to anything, it's too general.

- The freezes question is probably [bug-reporting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bug-reporting)
- I agree, [release-management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/release-management)
- This one is a wikipedia article, not an AU question IMO

The other two are straightfoward.

Comment: The third one I voted it to close, sadly it didn't got closed...